# redirectUrls does not exist on type 'Microsoft.DirectoryServices.WebApplication'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Beta Graph API to auto deploy dev env where I auto update a WebApplication's callback urls.

This has been working for a while has suddenly stopped working. As per https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/web.md it should accept redirectUrls under the web property.

```
{
  "logoutUrl": "String",
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
  "redirectUrls": ["String"]
}
```

I am now getting the following error from microsoft graph api

> The property 'redirectUrls' does not exist on type
>   'Microsoft.DirectoryServices.WebApplication'. Make sure to only use
>   property names that are defined by the type.

Also when querying the applications via https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application it's no longer returning the redirectUrls under the web property.

I am confused?? Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog.. Maybe this made the changes ahead of time..

Comment: I ran into something similar attempting to create the application with the redirectUrl in the json payload. Best I can do is create the application, then patch it.